# Why is the boostrap widget not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a date picker into my website using boostrap. I've never used it before, I don't understand the error that keeps coming up.

.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sidebar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/taskboard.css">

<script src="javascripts/taskboard.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 
.
.
.
<div style="overflow:hidden; z-index:100;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: true
              });
            });
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Nothing shows when I load the website, it stays empty and I get a console messsage saying:
[image]

Comment: @FareedKhan i used this link (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to get that html code, there is no css file, i thought that adding the href's in the links would be okay

Comment: double check your file Path for the CSS-File mentioned in the Error-Message. It Can happen that a slight typo in the path gives back a HTML-File with 404 Error, so it gets recognized as HTML not CSS and gives you this Error instead of a non reply. Easiest way to try this is: Try to open the file directly. Just put your path from the href in a new Tab in your Browser and see if it works. If not there could be other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working perfectly fine with `cdn`

here is the [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/xuo2ck3d/)

You should double check whether the css files are in the correct location.

If they are then you can try few solutions here

1. Try removing the `rel="stylesheet"` property and adding `type="text/html"` in the link tag.
2. If the first solution didn't work then you can try keeping `rel="stylesheet"` and additionally add the `type="text/css"`
3. if both of the above mentioned solution didn't work then you try adding `<base href="/">` before your `link` tags

[image]

Comment: it tells me to run 'bower install eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker#latest --save' on my terminal but that returns a bash command not found error

Comment: that's because you need to install `bower` first by using this: `npm install -g bower` then you can use `bower install eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker#latest --save` here is the guide for you to install bower: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower